# Display 5 digit Julian Date in IFRAME

Tags: javascript, html, date, iframe, julian-date

I have a locally hosted (on my machine) simple HTML page that we use in the office for tracking work orders.  I made it as simple as possible.  One dynamic element I need is to display the 5 digit Julian date inside of an IFRAME.

The format needs to be (ex):  24043
24 for the last two of the year, and 043 being the 43rd day of this calendar year (February 12, 2024).

I have tried multiple different posts, and guides to get this working, but none of them thus far has worked correctly, or most times, at all.

Here is the code I have in my HEAD at the moment:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('txt').julianDate;
//set an array with day counts for all months
var dayCount = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];

function convertDate(str) {
   //convert passed string to date object
   var dte = new Date(str);
   //initialize date variable
   var julianDate = 0;
   //add days for previous months
   for (i = 0; i < dte.getMonth(); i++) {
      julianDate += dayCount[i];
   }
   //add days of the current month
   julianDate += dte.getDate();
   //check for leap year
   if (dte.getFullYear() % 4 == 0 && dte.getMonth() > 1) {
      julianDate++;
   }
   //alert("Julian Date: " + julianDate);
   //var jdate = julianDate
   //return julianDate;
   document.getElementById("JulianDate").innerHTML = julianDate2
}
</script>
```

And in the body (as a test) I have this:

```
<h1>"The value for number is: " <span id="JulianDate2"></span></h1>
```

My current output is:

> "The value for number is: "

with no value being put out.  I'm not a programming whiz by any means, so I have to look most of this up, and work my way though it the best I can.

Comment: What is `txt`. What is `julianDate2` ? Where is `JulianDate` ? You never call `convertDate`

Comment: For the calculation, there are many popular date libraries available, which are likely robust and thoroughly tested. I recommend using one, such as dayjs, https://day.js.org/, and using their "dayOfYear" api as a place to start to get the day part of your Julian date

Comment: To  be clear, this code snippet was taken from another post somewhere else.  I would have to sort through it to find it, I don't remember where off the top of my head.  I did not write it.  But I did try to decode it.